# Android Edittext Rich Text Formatting

Tags: android, android-edittext, rich-text-editor

Is there any library or open source application demo that contains Rich Text Format Edittext  component with WYSIWYG interface. I've heard that android-richtexteditor contained such functionality, but it's source code is no longer available.

If anyone have a link or source to the above please share it with me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are two awesome libraries which helped me out. Both of them are implementation of WYSIWYG.

Android RTEditor:
https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor

RichEditor-Android:
https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android

Their implementation code is also provided.

Comment: Thanks for the libraries, i'll use them in the future :).

Comment: I was looking for the same queries and the answer provided in this page was not satisfactory. So i thought I will write one.

Comment: Your answer currently is more actual, because there wasn't any WYSIWYG editor library about 2 years ago, when i asked that question.

Comment: I used the rich editor library and got exception
**Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 at file:///android_asset/rich_editor.js** Anyone had the same issue??

Answer (score 3):

No there is no library for this but you can do that with using following classes

1.HTML

2.SPANNABLE

3.ForegroundSpan

4.BackgroundSpan

5.AbsoluteSpan

1.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

using this you can embedd direct html tag with android like bold ,itlic,underlince  etc

2.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html
(SpannableString ,SpannableStringBuilder, etc)

**EDIT**

for edit text bold,italic etc.. see some examples on below link

http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/08/easy-method-for-formatting-android.html

https://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/

Comment: Thanks for the info. One more question - which class can i use to implement things like selected text alignment to left, right, center ?

Comment: you can use HTML class for that you will find the method HTML.fromHtml("here you can directly embed you html code of left rigth text") and set it to spannableString and set spannableStrig to your textView done.+1 accept

Comment: @Hardik, i tried to use that html -bold- inside the edittext, but seems no change? Why is that happened like that?

Comment: @gumuruh thanks for your feedback, i have edit a answer for you see official example to know better idea how to do it.

Comment: Official example link goes to a basic Getting Started guide now.

Comment: @MichaelFulton I changed link...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the steps to convert an EditText into RichText

1) Create a RichTextEditor class as shown below, this example has support for bold/unbold, you can add more as needed

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.loa.learnandcheck.R;
import com.loa.learnandcheck.util.ResourceHelper;

public class RichTextEditor implements ImageButton.OnClickListener, TextWatcher {
    private boolean textBold;
    private ImageButton buttonBold;
    private EditText editText;
    private Activity parent;
    private int styleStart = 0;

    public RichTextEditor(Activity parent, EditText editText){
        try {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.editText = editText;
            init();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void init(){
        try {
            buttonBold = (ImageButton)parent.findViewById(R.id.text_control_text_bold);
            if(buttonBold!=null) {
                buttonBold.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Activity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Activity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void updateBackground(boolean itemSelected, ImageButton button) {
        try {
            if(itemSelected) {
                button.setBackgroundColor(ResourceHelper.getThemeColor(parent,R.color.colorGray, Color.GRAY));
            } else {
                button.setBackgroundColor(ResourceHelper.getThemeColor(parent,R.color.colorWhite, Color.WHITE));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void handleBoldButtonClick() {
        try {
            textBold = !textBold;
            updateBackground(textBold,buttonBold);
            int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
            int selectionEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();
            if (selectionStart > selectionEnd){
                int temp = selectionEnd;
                selectionEnd = selectionStart;
                selectionStart = temp;
            }
            if (selectionEnd > selectionStart) {
                Spannable str = editText.getText();
                StyleSpan[] ss = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, StyleSpan.class);
                boolean exists = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
                    if (ss[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD){
                        str.removeSpan(ss[i]);
                        exists = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!exists){
                    str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void handleFormat(Editable s, int position, int format) {
        try {
            StyleSpan[] ss = s.getSpans(styleStart, position, StyleSpan.class);
            for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
                if (ss[i].getStyle() == format){
                    s.removeSpan(ss[i]);
                }
            }
            s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(format), styleStart, position, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.text_control_text_bold:
                    handleBoldButtonClick();
                    break;
                //more formats to be handled as needed here...
                default:
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int position = Selection.getSelectionStart(editText.getText());
        //handle bold
        if (textBold){
            handleFormat(s, position, android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
        }
        //more formats to be handled as needed here...
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        styleStart = start;
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //unused
    }

}
```

2) Create the following ResourceHelper class

```
public class ResourceHelper {
    /**
     * Get a color value from a theme attribute.
     * @param context used for getting the color.
     * @param attribute theme attribute.
     * @param defaultColor default to use.
     * @return color value
     */
    public static int getThemeColor(Context context, int attribute, int defaultColor) {
        int themeColor = 0;
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        try {
            Context packageContext = context.createPackageContext(packageName, 0);
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo =
                context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            packageContext.setTheme(applicationInfo.theme);
            Resources.Theme theme = packageContext.getTheme();
            TypedArray ta = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {attribute});
            themeColor = ta.getColor(0, defaultColor);
            ta.recycle();
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return themeColor;
    }
}
```

3) Create layout with an edittext and control buttons(ImageButtons) as shown below

```
   <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="5"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"

                android:hint="@string/text_content" />


<ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/text_control_text_bold"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_text_bold"/>
```

4) In Activity, load the edittext and create RichTextEditor instance as show below

```
inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_content) ;
new RichTextEditor(this,inputText);
```

Comment: Got exception
**Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 at file:///android_asset/rich_editor.js**  Can you tell me what's wrong

Comment: @Karan sharma Looks like you are using a different suggestion (.js) file, and  there seems to be a syntax error in your rich_editor.js file

Comment: Actually library was working fine initially now i got this exception in logcat.

Comment: It is giving error : 
Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must grant uri permissions