# Android : Using multiple WebViews in one activity

Tags: android, webview

I am making a simple note taking application in which I'm saving notes in HTML format to support Rich Text Formatting. As far as viewing notes is concerned, I'm using WebView to show HTML formatted text. But, I want to show multiple notes on same activity. That increases the number of different WebViews.

Will that affect the performance of my app? Is it a good option to use WebViews to achieve this? I'm confused and unaware of better methods to do this.

Comment: how do you save the notes in HTML ?

Comment: I am using one of the classes available in this project https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android

Comment: I have checked RichTextEditor class in the above mentioned link. I felt all features are available in native with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767022/android-edittext-rich-text-formating. Then creating multiple views(either textview/webview) has to be reconsidered unless unavoidable.

Comment: I have tried using native methods to do this. But there are limitations such as CSS cannot be parsed using Html class.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a good option to use WebViews here. If you want to show spanned text you can use TextView, e.g.:

```
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml("<b>Your string with tags here</b>");
textView.setText(spanned);
```

Comment: Html.fromHtml() supports a limited number of tags. It doesn't support CSS. What possible problems are there in using WebView?

Comment: Well, if you really need CSS, then I think you don't have an option other than using a WebView. How do you want to show multiple WebViews, in the ListView? I think WebView is a bit heavy for this purpose and you will have problems with recycling them. If you don't use recycling, then you should keep all WebViews in memory which is also not great..