# Show number of lines in text editor

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I want to make text editor in which I want to show `number of lines` wrote shown at left side of screen

Like in this picture the number of lines wrote in edit text shown like 1,2,3,etc

[image]

I also want when user scroll up or down the number of lines also scroll. Advance thanks

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.osama.cryptofmroot.extras.TextEditorActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/type_here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/editor_area"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        />

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: If that isn't possible with the widget you have decided using, you can either create your own (create a new class extending the APpCOmpatEditText) or find a library.

Comment: i just want to number of lines on left side of screen is it possible ??

Comment: If you can't do it with AppCompatEditText you have to create your own class extending AppCompatEditText or find a library to do it. I don't know if you can show lines in it, so that is something you have to figure out. Find the documentation, see if there is any way to show line numbers. If there isn't create your own version or find a library

Comment: Like @LunarWatcher said, you need to create a CustomView your own, or use a library (if exists) for that.

Comment: [Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33101274/6296561)

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are using an EditText view, so here you could find a tutorial how to create a custom EditText in which you will have the line numbers included:

https://mahbubzaman.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/custom-edittext-with-line-number/

I hope it will help you :)