# how to fetch formatted text from database and reproduce them on a textview in my recyclerView

Tags: android, textview

Here is my problem:

I have a simple recyclerView whose list item contains only two textViews. One is for displaying date and the other is for content which is supposed to be fetched from my database.

In my case,when I click on the list item and I will jump to another activity, within which I take some note in an editText. I then save the content of the note into database and I managed to show the content on the list item when I go back to the former activity which contains the recyclerView. 
[formatted text in EditText looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0JCb.png)

But when I go back to the recyclerView, the text will be look like this:
[text showed unformatted in list item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eaufi.png)

Do you guys have any idea what I should do to reproduce the text format properly? And by the way, I'd appreciate it if you guys can provide some advice on how to achieve rich text function in an editText!

Thanks in advance and have a nice day :)

Comment: Post some code, guessong otherwise

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33101274/4824088

Comment: I end up using `wasabeef/richeditor-android` on GitHub and re-formatting my text using `Jsoup`. I hope this comment might be helpful for those who are suffering from the same problem as I did :)